# How to compare strings in python

Tags: python

I am using python 2.7. I am running a linux command using python which prints out the wifi ssid available. I need to compare if the ssid I am trying to connect is available or not. I am using the below command to print the ssid:

```
import commands
ret = commands.getstatusoutput("sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID")
print(ret)

#output:    
(0, ESSID="SSID1"\n
    ESSID="SSID2"\n
    ESSID="SSID3")
```

if I print `print(ret[1])` then it gives below output:

```
    ESSID="SSID1"
    ESSID="SSID2"
    ESSID="SSID3"
```

Lets say I am trying to connect to `SSID2`, how can I put this in a condition to check if `SSID2` is available at this moment or not. Something like `if ret[1] == "SSID2"`. I am new to python programming.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `if ret[1] == "SSID2"` ?

Comment: @khelwood No. I dont think it will work because ret[1] has other text too.

Comment: Look, if has 2 probable cases. True or false. If it is other text, then if block won't get executed

Comment: Also note that the output as shown does not quote the second element in the tuple, i.e. the string containing the command's output. It therefore seems there may have been a copy-and-paste error or similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ret[1]` is a newline-separated string. Each line has an equals sign in it. You need an expression that evaluates to `True` when `"SSID2"` appears on the right-hand side of any equals sign.

```
data = '''\
ESSID="SSID1"
ESSID="SSID2"
ESSID="SSID3"'''
if any(x.split('=')[1][1:-1]=="SSID2" for x in data.splitlines()):
    print("yes")
```

`data.splitlines()` returns a sequence of the lines in `data` (you could use `ret[1]` for this).  For each line `x`, `x.split('=')` returns a list where the first element is the string to the left of the equals sign and the second is that to the right. So `x.split('=')[1]` is the right-hand side, and `x.split('=')[1][1:-1]` removes the first and last (quote) characters.

This is wrapped up in a generator expression that produces a sequence of arguments to the built-in `any` function, which returns `True` as soon as it encounters an argument that evaluates true.

Answer (score -4):

```
if "SSID2" in "ret[1].split("\n")[1]":
    print "yes"
```

Comment: This will only work if the SSID you're looking for just so happens to be the 2nd one in the list...